# Struggling with a SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table called transaction

```
Transaction:
  User_Id: int
  Transaction_Type: int
  Amount: int
```

How would I query all users that do not have transaction type 1.

```
SELECT * FROM Transaction WHERE Transaction_Type <> 1 Group By User_Id
```

seems to return all users & their transaction types that are not = to 1.  I need all users that are missing / have no record of type 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with an `IN()` subquery

```
SELECT DISTINCT User_Id FROM Transaction
WHERE User_Id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT User_Id FROM Transaction WHERE Transaction_Type = 1)
```

Or with a `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT User_Id 
FROM Transaction t
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT User_Id FROM Transaction tn WHERE Transaction_Type = 1) 
  AND t.User_Id = tn.User_Id
```

Comment: @AnthonyGrist And +1 for you for just missing it.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a more elegant way of doing this, but this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM Transaction WHERE User_Id NOT IN (SELECT User_Id FROM Transaction WHERE Transaction_Type = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM    ( SELECT DISTINCT User_Id FROM Transaction ) AS User
LEFT JOIN Transaction ON Transaction.User_Id         = User.id
                     AND Transaction.Transaction_Id != 1
WHERE Transaction.Transaction_Id IS NULL
GROUP BY User.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT User_Id
FROM Transaction
WHERE Transaction_Id <> 1
GROUP BY User_Id
```

This gets each `User_Id` which has at least one transaction which is not of type 1. If you also want the ones with no transactions, add `OR Transaction_Id IS NULL` to the `WHERE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
SELECT DISTINCT User_Id
FROM [Transaction]
EXCEPT
SELECT User_Id
FROM [Transaction]
WHERE Transaction_Id = 1
```

That's if you don't have a separate table for users. If you do, then use an outer join.

I would suggest not using keywords (like `Transaction`) as table/column names

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this with a `JOIN`. Assuming a `Users` table:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Transaction t
ON t.User_ID = u.User_ID
AND t.Transaction_Type = 1
WHERE t.User_ID IS NULL
```

This method avoids the subquery and `DISTINCT`.